# Intermediate Service between client and SOLR search

Tags: solr

I want to create some custom search logic.
I found the logic quite custom so I dont see how this can implemented by extending SOLR.

More specifically, I want client to use the id to perform a search to find similar items of the same category. But the returned results need to be filtered with some very custom logic.

For that reason, I think I want to implement some custom service that will expose a REST API to the client and then it will forward the request to SOLR search.

Do you think that I can avoid this option by extending SOLR search implementation?

Which is best practice?

Comment: it's unclear what you asking, but in general you could extend Solr to create your custom query, but in most of cases default queries will be enough for 80% of tasks

Comment: Can this custom logic be stored as a field in the index, or does it have to be calculated at the query time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice is to have a layer between Solr and the client anyway. Solr does not have security out of the box and anybody who can access it can issue delete commands as well as the search one.

So, doing a REST interface to the client and talking to Solr via a secure link (firewall/IP protected) is the good practice.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you Alexandre.

Comment: In terms of search result processing. I wonder whether this layer can have additional logic to filter out some of the search results. Or extending solr using plugin would be handier and easier to implement? What is your view?

Comment: Depends on the logic. If it's inside Solr, you don't have to reconstruct documents to send to clients. Filters are pretty good to be inside Solr, especially with recent post-filter improvements. So, it's more efficient. But if you are doing some super-complex processing, it might be easier logically on the client. No single answer.